# Charting solution in iOS (native / Javascript)

Tags: javascript, ios, charts

I am beginner in iOS development and looking for opensource(or lowcost) solution for **charting** in iOS. I have some experience with **core-plot** library, it's quite sufficient in basic drawing, but I'm not satisfied with **interaction** posibillities.  So do you know some native opensource solutions or some good JS library with user interaction support(gestures etc.) and offline drawing ?

**And what approach do you suggest according to your experience? Native(Obj.C) or JS solutions ?**

Comment: http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ - learning curve is a little steep, but it's fantastic stuff.

Comment: very interesting charts, thanks! Do you have some experience with this lib?

Comment: I do. It took a while to understand, but it's been worth it. Go through the tutorials and keep in mind that you are essentially gluing data to elements of your html and have fun!

Comment: This JavaScript charting library seems good for your needs - http://www.fusioncharts.com/products/suite/whats-new/. See my answer below..

Answer (score 1):

For js I used the following offline libraries:

- [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/): Is a open source library, it doesn't have really fancy chart, has events for the charts, is not cross browser.
- [jqplot](http://www.jqplot.com/): Is free, In my opinion has better chart than flot, it doesn´t have events.
- [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/): Is free for personal or non-profit project, this library has beautiful charts, is cross browser and has events.

For a IOS develop you can use the previous libraries if you are coding for example with phonegap.

I hope it can help you!!

Comment: You dont have to use phonegap, you can set up a uiwebview in your project and display it in there.  In my opinion it would be silly to learn phonegap just to make an iOS project.  However I loathe JS and HTML so my opinion is not objective...

Comment: I didn´t know about the uiwebview, when I developed an app for IOS I did it with phonegap (I couldn´ t access to a mac), developing with phonegap has some advantages for example is cross platform and some disadvantages like you don´t feel the app as if it were native.

Comment: Hello Borrrden, i have the similar requirement. I would like to use HighChart or amChart in my native iOS application using UIWebView? can you please give some pointer how to start this? I've no prior experience on Java Script & UIWebView though i know obj C programming.

Answer (score 0):

Try using FusionCharts XT within a UIWebView.

This is an excellent tutorial where you can read about how to [create charts for iOS apps using FusionCharts XT](http://blog.fusioncharts.com/2012/02/create-charts-for-iphone-and-ipad-apps-using-fusioncharts-xt/).

They provide a full-featured trial version for unlimited duration.

Comment: haha he said open source or lowcost.  I'm sure you know how costly are the FC. They're the best in their arena though.

Answer (score 0):

For a IOS developer you can use --
 **MIM chart library.
 core plot Libraries.**
it will used to you can easily customize charts.please find the following links to reference. 
https://github.com/ReetuRaj/MIMChart-Library
https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot